# Location a specific model with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm very new to CodeIgniter and am currently in the process of rewriting a site of mine so that it's compatible with CI. I have controller file located at `/application/controllers/user.php`

```
if(!defined('BASEPATH')) 
{
    exit('No direct script access allowed');
} else
{   
    class user extends CI_Controller 
    {
        public function index() 
        {   
            $this->load->library('customautoloader');
            $this->load->model('user', '', true);   


            $data = array('title' => 'Title goes here',
                        'body' => 'The string to be embedded here!');

            $this->load->library('template');
            $this->template->load('default', null, $data);
        }

    }   
}
```

**In application/models/user.php, I have the following:**

```
namespace models; // set namespace

if(! defined('BASEPATH')) 
{
    exit('No direct script access allowed'); 
} else
{
    class User
    {   
         ...
    }
 }
```

When I put the following url into my browser:

```
http://localhost:8888/CodeIgniter/user/
```

I'm greeted with an error message that reads:

> "Fatal error: Call to a member function load() on a non-object"

I know this may be a simpleton question, but I'm very new to CI and the rules that it uses.

Thanks

Comment: Unless user is in the folder admin it won't work.  You have $this->load->model('admin/user', '', true);  .  But you specify the user.php is in application/models/user.php.

Comment: Sorry. That was a typo. I specified the correct location and am greeted with "Fatal error: Call to a member function load() on a non-object"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you should extends CI_Model in application/models/user.php

```
 class User extends CI_Model {

        // your codes here
 }
```

Here is the document for using Codeigniter model http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html

Comment: Just tried that and it says "Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'application/models/CI_Model.php'"

Comment: Got it finally after some fiddling.